# How to create a shared folder

Tags: permissions, shared-folders

How do I setup a shared folder / common used folder under linux with standard linux permissions?
My requirements are:

- Only specified users have write permissions.
- If a user writes a folder other write enabled users shall be able to edit them. (It shall be irrelevant who created a file - the other user shall be able to edit them.)

My first try was a group named `shared_data` and one user and the group owns the directory with ls -l giving

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 user   shared_data  4096 Nov  8 18:11 shared_data
```

but if `user` creates a folder it belongs to the group `user` and not to the group `shared_data`.

```
user@shared_folder$ touch test
user@shared_folder$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Nov  8 18:16 test
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/277775/ensuring-new-files-in-a-directory-belong-to-the-group), you want to set the setgid bit on the directory:

```
$ chmod g+s shared_data
```

All new files created in the directory will have the group set to the group of the directory.

Comment: I created a subfolder with `userA` and it worked that it now belongs to group `shared_data` but `userB` (also in this group) can't write files in the subfolder.

Comment: My problem was that I had to login with each user after adding him to the group.